# Getting specified rows from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, echo

Am making a really simple php page which pulls data from a really simple database and displays it as charts for a wall monitor.

I've got the data from the db, no problem, but I seem to be struggling splitting that data up

For now i'm just echoing the data to make sure i have what i need.

My code looks like this:

```
    <?php 
     mysql_connect("host", "user", 'password' or die(mysql_error()); 
     mysql_select_db("databax") or die(mysql_error()); 
     $dbdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbcpman_resources") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 
     $column = mysql_fetch_array( $dbdata );
     echo $column[0]."<br>";
     echo $column[1]."<br>";
     echo $column[2]."<br>";
     echo $column[3]."<br>";
     echo $column[4]."<br>";
     echo $column[5]."<br>";
     ?>
```

Indeed, it works - it will echo data from the database, but as i've not specified the row anywhere, its just giving me the first row.

I need to be able to work with each row seperately.
There will only ever be 6 rows in this table.

So can anyone help me out with how I go about replicating this for rows 2,3,4,5 and 6?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: You need a cycle (`for`, `while`, etc...) to fetch multiple rows.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this line `$column = mysql_fetch_array( $dbdata );` in while loop like this

```
while($column = mysql_fetch_array( $dbdata ))
{
echo $column[0]."<br>";
 echo $column[1]."<br>";
 echo $column[2]."<br>";
 echo $column[3]."<br>";
 echo $column[4]."<br>";
 echo $column[5]."<br>";

}
```

Comment: Would i need to use an if statement to assign value to specific variables?

the columns in my db are : type, capacitytotal, capacityused, percentused.

My end goal is to be able to use these values with google charts like so...

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Resource', 'capacity'],
          ['Used',     <?php echo $memoryused ?>],
   ['Available',     <?php echo $memoryavailable ?>],

etc

Comment: sorry i dont have ideas about google charts,also i cant get your question `Would i need to use an if statement to assign value to specific variables?`

Comment: nevermind, you're response is ultimately the correct answer, i just need to wake my brain up a little more :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the result set. The easiest way is to use a `while` loop as this automatically terminates at the end of the result set, like this.

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $dbdata );
   echo $row [0]."<br>";
   echo $row [1]."<br>";
   echo $row [2]."<br>";
   echo $row [3]."<br>";
   echo $row [4]."<br>";
   echo $row [5]."<br>";
}
```

Also if you were to change the function that returns the resuilts to use mysql_fetch_assoc() you can reference each field with the name it has on the database so the code is easier to read, like this:

I dont know your field names so I made some up.

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $dbdata );
   echo $row ['name']."<br>";
   echo $row ['date']."<br>";
   echo $row ['time']."<br>";
   echo $row ['value1']."<br>";
   echo $row ['value2']."<br>";
   echo $row ['value3']."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd rather use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of [mysql_fetch_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) since it doesn't srew up your result, if the table structure changes.
It would be even better if you used either [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.pdo.php) instead of `mysql_*` functions, since they are marked deprecated already!

Second please note, that either function just fetches ONE record from your resultset at a time. To fetch all records try the following:

```
$records = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbdata)) {
  $records[] = $row;
}
```

You can do a `print_r($records);` to see what's inside `$records` after fetching all.